# If $S$ and $T$ are functions which commute prove that $(S+T)^2 = S^2 + 2(S \circ T) + T^2$ , something is missing?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The problem is exercise 25 given in section 2.8 of *Calculus Vol.II* by Apostol :

> Given a linear space $V$ and functions $S : V \to V$ and $T : V \to V $ such that $S \circ T = T \circ S $ , prove that $(S+T)^2 = S^2 + 2(S \circ T) +T^2 $

$(S+T)^2 $ has to be understood as the composition of the function $S+T$ with itself.

---

What I managed to do is this :

$$(S+T)^2 = (S+T) \circ(S+T) $$

By definition of the sum of two functions we have

$$ (S+T) \circ(S+T)= S \circ(S+T) + T \circ(S+T) $$

and here I'm stuck. How can I continue?

I suspect there is a missing assumption which could be that $S$ and $T$ are linear trasformations. Is this the case?

Comment: Try proving the circle function to be the same as the multiplication function.

Comment: Indeed, you can't proceed further unless you have any additional assumptions on $S$ and $T$, such as linearity.

Comment: thank you @Sangchul Lee, I suspected it was like that !

Comment: This is a special case of the identity $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ for any two commuting elements $x$ and $y$ of a ring. Here, the relevant ring is the endomorphism ring of $V$ (assuming that $S$ and $T$ are linear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counterexample :

Take $ V = \mathbb{R}$ with functions $S(x) = x+1$ and $T(x) = x+2$ then

$$(S+T)\circ (S+T) = (2x+3) \circ (2x+3) = 4x +9$$

while

$$S^2 + 2 (S\circ T) + T^2 = (x+1)+1 + 2( (x+2)+1) + (x+2)+2 = 4x + 12$$

So the two expressions are not equivalent and therefore the theorem is not true without any further assumption.